# JavaFX LineChart How to draw line over symbol

Tags: javafx, linechart

I draw 2 series on one LineChart. First series - 
purple dots, second series - white line. I draw line after points, but 
points are drawn above the line.

How I can draw line over dots ?
[image]

Comment: Change the order in which you add your series to the series list?

Comment: Series of line was added after series of dots.

Comment: As I understand, this is property of series (or chart), that dots are drawn always above the lines. 
Is there any way to change this property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved with one line of code:

```
lineSeries.getNode().toFront();
```